# Triangle Imageview in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to create this type of view in Swift 3 . How we create I am unable to do this Please help Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: **I want to create this type of view in Swift 3** it means?

Comment: It sounds like you want to mask an image view with a triangle path?

Comment: Won't it help to have a triangle shaped image with transparency?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to crop an image to a shape of a triangle? I made an example for this case

```
func createTriangleImage() {
    // your UIImage
    let ballImage = UIImage(named: "ball")!

    // your imageView which you wanted to be triangle. 
    // I made the example via layers as it seems easier to me
    // so you dont need UIImageView here, UIView is enough
    let viewWithImage = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))

    // Layer for your image
    let imageLayer = CALayer()
    // Setting the image
    imageLayer.contents = ballImage.cgImage
    imageLayer.frame = viewWithImage.frame
    viewWithImage.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)

    //view - is your main view where you wanted to put the triangle image
    view.addSubview(viewWithImage)

    // Creating a triangle path to draw triangle mask later
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 40))
    path.close()

    // Creating a mask layer
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    // Setting the mask
    imageLayer.mask = maskLayer
}
```